# foreign_key is always 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to enter a foreign key value along with data collected from a form. The form data is submitting perfectly, but the foreign key is always entering as 1. I have tried several ways of entering the info, my current create method attempt is below:

```
def create

    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    @username = User.select("company").where("email= ?", current_user.email.to_s)
    @cid = User.select("id").where("company= ?", @username)

    if @username != nil    
      @product.company_id = @cid
      @product.save 
    end

end
```

Also, the find_by_something (and to_i) method throws up a No Such Method error, so I have used the above query syntax as a work around. If anyone can explain that as an aside...

Edit, The models: User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :company

  validates :company, :presence => true
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

  after_save :correspond


  def correspond
    c = Company.find_or_create_by_name(self.company)
  end

end
```

Company Model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :product, :foreign_key => 'company_id', :class_name => 'Product'

end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  validates :brand, :presence => true

end
```

Comment: ... why are you trying to find things by id instead of by name or something? Can you show us what your forms look like? Also, we'll need to know your relationships between your models. IE: product belongs_to company, user belongs_to company, company has_many products, company has_many users?

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Is `company` a field in the `users` table, or are you trying to reference an association?

Comment: I am selecting id because I want to insert that into the foreign key column. 
@Dan Cheail: company is a field in users.
Editing to include the forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dan's answer above is correct, but as a simpler version of it, to create the association you're describing you need:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :users
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

The Product and User tables need a column called `company_id`.

That's it! Now ActiveRecord will associate the objects intelligently on your behalf, and you can do things like:

```
@product = Product.new(params[:product])
@product.company = current_user.company
@product.save
```

The best way to understand how all these relationships work is to play with them in the console. Try things like:

```
Company.first.products
Company.find(2).products
Company.find_by_name('Acme').products.order('price DESC')
User.last.products.where(...)
```

and so on...

Lastly, a thought: You would benefit immensely from reading an introductory book on Rails. I recommend '[Beginning Rails 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224339)'. It's a fast read, you could work through it in a weekend, and it will make the big picture of how and WHY rails works the way it works very clear to you. The time spent reading the book will QUADRUPLE your productivity and the speed at which you learn more advanced stuff, because you'll be starting with a solid foundation and approaching problems "the rails way."

Your problem today was definitely a case of "you're doing it wrong", which doesn't mean there's anything wrong with your logic, just that you're making a simple problem much more difficult by trying to reinvent the wheel unnecessarily. Learning "the rails way" will make you much more productive, and will make the whole thing a lot more fun.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is very informative, and Beginning Rails 3 looks to be a good read. However, I don't really think anyone understood quite what I was trying to do. This is probably more due to my poor explanation than anything though. I have since resolved the issue, implementing what was described above with changes to fit the exact scenario. Mostly, thanks for taking the time out to help me out! much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. I hope you'll find the rails community in general is quite supportive, that's been my experience anyway. Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after the lengthy discussion in the comments, this is what I believe you need:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :lockable and :timeoutable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

  # You'll need to add a new column to your users table, called `company_id`
  belongs_to :company
end

# app/models/company.rb
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has_many should _always_ be a pluralised version of the class you're associating. This way, you 
  # don't need to explicitly specify the class/foreign_keys
  has_many :products

  # Also, you may as well link back to your Users
  has_many :users
end


# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  validates :brand, :presence => true
end


# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def create
  # and now, to associate the product with the company, all you need to do is this:

  @product = current_user.company.products.build(params[:product])

  if @product.save
    # redirect
  else
    # render and show errors
  end
end
```

Rails relies *heavily* on convention. You really, *really* should follow them to make your life easier.

Instead of your manual linking of `User` and `Company`, I've suggested that you use a proper association.

That way, inside your Controller, all you need to do is call `current_user.company` to get the company, then use the `build` method on the association, and Rails will automatically handle assigning foreign keys.

Comment: This answer is correct. I personally prefer to construct this type of relationship using `@product = Product.new(params[:product]); @product.company=current_user.company; @product.save`, but the method shown above will work exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have up above... which is quite confusing, I'm going to hazard a wild guess:

You might want to try:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  @product.company = current_user.company
  @product.save
  ...
end
```

The approach you were taking above shows good knowledge of SQL but also that you're not very familiar with Ruby or Rails. Let ActiveRecord make your life easy, you shouldn't ever be trying to manually set a foreign key, instead you should be building relationships using objects, as shown above.

As an aside in case you're not familiar with the convention, if you want to handle validation errors etc. in your controller you should use this where the elipsis is above:

```
if @product.save
  redirect_to ... # Redirect to whatever the next page you want them to see is if it saves correctly.
else
  render 'edit' # Otherwise show the edit view again with the errors that prevented saving
end
```

Comment: I had something like this originally. The confusing code is the result of many attempts at rectifying the error the above code gives me: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ProductController#create  Company(#30659196) expected, got String(#19723464). Calling to_s on current_user.company doesnt help either... You're right though, I'm not very familiar with ruby/rails. Writing string queries in java helps with the SQL though

Comment: Aha! THAT is your problem :)   Do you know for sure your `current_user` object is behaving correctly? Try putting `debug current_user` in the top of your view and looking at it in your browser. What do you get?

Comment: In the list of attributes printed by debug, the id attribute is 16. Everything seems correct. Its not possible in rails to have saved an object to the database through some magic, is it?

Comment: Your USER id is 16 or your COMPANY id is 16? Is Company a model in your database, and User belongs_to Company?

Comment: No, I have a Company model and a column company in users. I implemented this small redundancy on purpose.

Comment: Ok... so, like the error message says you have an association type mismatch. You can't have a field in your model called "company" if your model also belongs_to Company. You need to remove that field from your User table and just let ActiveRecord manage the association for you. If Company has_many Users and User belongs_to Company, then all you need is a `company_id:integer` column in your User table. Then when you call `current_user.company` you'll actually get the company object that the user belongs to, which you can use to build other associations (like telling a product to belong to it)

Comment: FYI: any time you create a column in your DB that has the same name as a method in your model, you're going to get bugs. In this case, user.company is a method created by the ActiveRecord association, and your company field in the user table is conflicting with it.

Comment: Hang on. You've got an association named `company` as well as a field named company? That's going to be the source of your problems / confusion. Rename the `company` COLUMN to something like `company_name`.

Comment: The primary key of the Company table is 16. I will make the change and see if that clears things up.

Comment: Okay, I've renamed the column to 'name'. The error is still occuring though. Also, I think there is some confusion here: I want to put the primary key of the Company table as the foreign key. The relation is company has_many product. I just need to get the current company by selecting it from the attributes associated with the current_user.

Comment: At this point you probably need to redo your question with the complete Product, Company, and User models. You're not building your associations right, but I'm not sure exactly how you're off without more a more detailed look at your code.

Comment: @providence: if Company has_many :products and has_many :users, and your current user object is working correctly, then `product.company = current_user.company` will work. Your associations must not be configured correctly to be getting the error message you're describing.

Comment: Have edited to show associations. This could well be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a lot of redundant queries here. You should be able to simplify this to just the following:

```
def create
    # so far, so good
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    # assuming that `current_user` returns an instance of User, you can replace the following two lines
    # @username = User.select("company").where("email= ?", current_user.email.to_s)
    # @cid = User.select("id").where("company= ?", @username)

    # Rather than going back to the database twice to get an ID, you can simply grab it from `current_user`
    unless current_user.company.blank?
      @product.company_id = current_user.id
      @product.save
    end

    # you should probably have an error handling / redirect / render routine here
end
```

That said, something about your logic seems a bit off. I would have expected `company_id` to refer to the id of an instance of `Company` not `User`

It could be that the reason your `company_id` is always 1 is because the `id` of the instance returned by `current_user` is 1.

Comment: Dan, based on what he's said so far, your option should say `@product.company_id = current_user.company.id`. He did tell us that company is a field in the users table.

Comment: Aye; `company` is a _field_ in the users table: not an association. `current_user.company.id` would throw an error, given that `current_user.company` would return a string, based on what he's said so far.

Comment: Heh. I now see where the confusion lies. :)

Comment: Hah, a field indeed! Nevermind my comment then, but I think we're getting to the bottom of this.